# Monotouch daemon application

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

Is there a way to create a daemon application for iOS, i'm not sure if daemons app are allowed in App Store, but Google Latitude does this in order to update user info when the application isn't loaded or in background.

Thanks.

Comment: I do not think so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014899/ios-daemons-are-they-legal-for-appstore

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not have services.

But you can setup your app to handle location updates when in the background.  (But if a user force-quits the app from double-tapping home, your app will no longer receive these events)

I would review the iOS docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html), not sure if there is a MonoTouch example, but you should be able to translated what you would do in Objective-C.

I would not think it would be a trivial task, however.